# Access data from an array of JTextField thats in an array of JPanels? -Sudoku

Tags: java, arrays

I'm creating a Sudoku board and I've created 9 JPanels that each hold 9 JTextFields. My problem is that I don't know how to get the input from a JTextField from just one SPECIFIC panel.

This is how I created each JTextField and JPanel. I've already initialised them in another method.

```
private JPanel panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4, panel5, panel6, panel7, panel8, panel9;

private JPanel[][] smallgrids = { {panel1, panel2, panel3}, {panel4, panel5, panel6}, {panel7, panel8, panel9} };

private JTextField cell1, cell2, cell3, cell4, cell5, cell6, cell7, cell8, cell9;

private JTextField[][] cells = { {cell1, cell2, cell3}, {cell4, cell5, cell6}, {cell7, cell8, cell9}};
```

This is what I did to get the input from each JTextField:

```
String input;
for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++){
        input = cells[x][y].getText();          
        cells[x][y].setText(input);

            }   
        }
        //this was my test to see if it would print the correct value
        System.out.println(input[0][0]);
```

My problem is that the loop accesses the input from a cell without specifying which panel it's from. How do I specify which panel I'm accessing the input from? Sorry if the wording is a little confusing. I can post all of my code if needed.

And this is what my board looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. Create a 9 x 9 array of JTextFields -- now the main issue has been solved as any and all JTextField is accessible by simple use of the appropriate indexes.
2. Create a 3 x 3 array of JPanels, and give each JPanel 9 of the appropriate JTextFields from above.
3. Most important, create a model class with a 9 x 9 array of ints, or perhaps better, enums, since soduku numbers don't behave as true numbers, but rather any 9 item collection of unique items would work.
4. The model will have 9 squares to correspond to the JPanels, and which will hold 9 enum items each
5. You'll also need row and column collections to test for row and column logical validity (no duplicate enum entries).

Answer (score 0):

Your smallgrids is a 2d array of JPanels.  your cells is a 2d array of JTextFields.  Right now you only have one of each, from the look of your code.

With your current design, you need one grid of JTextFields for each JPanel in your smallgrids array.  I might create and initialize these values like this:

```
public void init_grids(){
    // create the outer grid.
    JPanel[][] grid = NEW JPanel[3][3];

    // for each cell of the outer grid
    for (int x1 = 0; x1 < 3; x1++) {
        for (int y1 = 0; y1 < 3; y1++) {

            // create the array of textfields for this panel.
            JTextField[][] textFields = new JTextField[3][3];
            grid[x1][y1] = textFields;

            // for each cell of the inner grid
            for (int x2 = 0; x2 < 3; x2++) {
                for (int y2 = 0; y2 < 3; y2++) {

                    // create the text field.
                    textFields[x2][y2] = new JTextField();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

access it by:

```
// 1st 2 indices are outer grid, 2nd 2 are the inner grid.
grid[x1][y1][x2][y2].getText();
```